# I have redirected my page using htaccess but all my css, images and jquery is breaking

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

My htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^example1/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ example2.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

My page is getting loaded but all the css and js are getting broke.
Please Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the request uri matches the existing file / director before applying the `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^example1/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ example2.php?name=$1 [NC]
```